# Run laravel job in each api instance

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I have 5 api servers on production environment, my task is to push large files to s3, because it will take time, I will use laravel job dispatch, my problem is when running laravel job Make sure the job has retrieved the correct file from the storage where the file is being stored. How to configure each api job will take files from its own storage and push to s3